# How can I set public channel without any authentication on broadcasting laravel?

Tags: laravel, notifications, laravel-5.3, real-time, broadcasting

I read here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting#concept-overview

There explains that it can use public channel. But there is no example of how to use it

I just see an example of a private channel like this :

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('user.'.$this->user->id);
}
```

I need a real example of public channel

I've tried searching, but I have not found it yet

Is there anyone can help?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

if the `Channel` class is not used in your event, add this line:

```php
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
```

you have to return a `Channel`:

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new Channel('myPublicChannelName');
}
```

An example can be found here: https://petericebear.github.io/starting-laravel-echo-20170303/

Comment: I say without anything authentication. Means there should not be this : `$this->user->id`. Your code is still using it

Comment: updated the code so now it has nothing to do with authentication. When you have a private channel, you must also authorized to join it.

Comment: Okay. But i'm still confused your code. This : `myPublicChannelName`. Where it is used?

Comment: You can listen to new events on this channel with your client. Because you could have multiple channels, but want to listen to just one of them.

Comment: Okay. Whether on the client side like this? `Echo.channel('myPublicChannelName')
    .listen('...', (e) => {
        console.log(e.order.name);
    });`.

Comment: Okay. I want ask again. This : `.listen('abc'`, Where `abc` is used?

Comment: You listen to your events on a channel https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting#listening-for-events. `abc` would be your laravel event, where you `boradcaston` method is located.

Comment: Okay. Is it like this ? `public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'abc';
    }`

Comment: No, `abc` is your EventClass name: `class abc implements ShouldBroadcast`. If you read the official documentation or the link I posted in my answer you will find all answers :)

Comment: I want ask again. Does it use listeners? Listeners here : `\myshop\app\Listeners\...`. Whether it needs to be listed here : `\myshop\app\Providers\EventServiceProvider.php`. Because every time using the event must use listener and register first through `EventServiceProvider`. But in the reference you provided, it does not exist

Comment: No, you do not need them for broadcasting. They are only needed if you want to listen to fired events with Laravel to do some things in the background. You only need them, when you use notifications, where you can broadcast to the notificationchannel of a special user, but you want to broadcast to a public channel so this is not relevant. I think not every event needs a listener and does not be added to the provider, but I have not checked it yet.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help. But I'm still fail. I make the new question which describes the details of my problem. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45903508/why-broadcasting-channel-public-not-working-laravel. I had follow your reference